# symfony 1.4 propel save embedForm one-to-one relationship

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, propel, admin-generator

I have two tables and this is how the schema looks like:

```
customer:
id:
username: { type: varchar, size: 50, required: true }
password: { type: varchar, size: 50, required: true }
hash: { type: varchar, size: 50, required: true }

customer_profile:
id: { type: integer, foreignTable: customer, foreignReference: id, primaryKey: true, required: true, onDelete: cascade, onUpdate: cascade}
country: { type: varchar, size: 80, required: true }
state: { type: varchar, size: 80, required: true }
city: { type: varchar, size: 80, required: true }
zip: { type: varchar, size: 80, required: true }

customer_info:
id: { type: integer, foreignTable: customer, foreignReference: id, primaryKey: true, required: true, onDelete: cascade, onUpdate: cascade}
preference: { type: longvarchar }
likes: { type: longvarchar }
```

I am currently using Symfony 1.4's (propel orm) admin but I can't successfully merge all these three forms into one.

```
public function configure()
{
$use_fields = array(........);
$sub_form1   = new CustomerProfileForm($this->getObject()->getCustomerProfile());
$this->embedForm('profile', $sub_form1);
array_push($use_fields, 'profile');

$sub_form1->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('customer_profile[%s]');
$sub_form2   = new CustomerInfoForm($this->getObject()->getCustomerInfo());
$this->embedForm('info', $sub_form2);
array_push($use_fields, 'info');
$sub_form2->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('customer_info[%s]');
$this->useFields($use_fields);
}

public function save($conn = null){
if ($forms === NULL)
 {
 $forms = $this->getEmbeddedForms();
 }
$forms['profile']->getObject()->setId($this->getObject()->getId());
$forms['profile']->save();
$forms['info']->getObject()->setId($this->getObject()->getId());
$forms['info']->save();
$this->getObject()->save();
}
```

However I get this error:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | sfValidatorErrorSchema

$this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('customer_profile[%s]');
$this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);
parent::setup();
```

I'm really stuck right now. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

I just want to have these three forms merged into one single admin form.

Comment: anybody? :( I'm still stuck at this. only the saving part is what's driving me crazy.. overriding the saveEmbeddedForm yields the same error. I'm really not sure where the validatorErrorSchema is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validatorErrorSchema is just an array of sfValidator objects that helps create an association with your form fields. Is that the entire error message?

Delete your code where you override the save() method. You should create the relationships between the Propel objects before you embed them in their corresponding forms like this:

```
public function configure()
{
    $use_fields = array(........);
    $profile = $this->getObject()->getCustomerProfile();
    // Do you assign profile objects if they don't exist?
    if (!$profile) {
        $profile = new CustomerProfile();
        $profile->setCustomer($this->getObject());
    }
    $profileForm = new CustomerProfileForm($profile);
    $this->embedForm('profile', $profileForm);
    array_push($use_fields, 'profile');


    $info = $this->getObject()->getCustomerInfo();
    // Do you assign info objects if they don't exist?
    if (!$info) {
        $info = new CustomerInfo();
        $info->setCustomer($this->getObject());
    }
    $infoForm = new CustomerInfoForm($info);
    $this->embedForm('info', $infoForm);
    array_push($use_fields, 'info');

    $this->useFields($use_fields);
}
```

Comment: anthony! thank you so much! this is exactly what I needed! I didn't know that this is the only way to fix the problem. Really really thanks!